# How did Roman babies talk?

Tags: classical-latin, roman-culture

Following a chat discussion, I want to know if we have any written record or general indication of how Latin was spoken by young children.

Most languages that I know have several distinct characteristics associated with baby talk: French children will often "faire dodo" instead of "dormir" (sleep), Latin American children often heavily use the diminutive ("¡Hay un conejito aquicito!"). Usually, sentence structure is simplified.

**Are there any works that preserve what this speech might have been like?** I'm mostly interested in classical times, but later evidence would certainly be welcome as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We know very little, and only about lexicon, thanks to grammarians and erudite writers (Varro). Also inscriptions.

Here is a list built from the Thesaurus linguae latinae and an old German article about baby talk in latin, [Die Sprache der römischen Kinderstube](https://ia800301.us.archive.org/7/items/archivfrlateini04wissgoog/archivfrlateini04wissgoog.pdf) by Wilhelm Heraeus (1904) (pp. 167-190 of the scanned pdf). Thanks @brianpck for looking up some of them.

- bua = potio
- pappa = cibum
- pappare = esse
- papa, appa = pater, papilla
- mamma, mama, amma = mater
- tata, atta = pater
- momma = mater, avia
- pupus = parvulus
- pupa = parvula, mammilla, *doll*
- abbo = basio
- ninna = cuna
- totto! = noli facere!
- siare = miare
- cacare, cunire = stercus facere
- inbulbitare (dub.) = puerili stercore inquinare
- poteaculum = *potty*
- lallare = *lullaby*
- [nutrices] infantibus, ut dormiant, saepe dicere solent: "lalla lalla lalla, aut dormi aut lacta" (scholia ad Persius, 3.16)
- pipiare = vagire

You should not trust the translations too much, because info is really scarce and often contradictory (partly because of the huge time and space span).

Comment: Welcome, and thanks for the interesting answer!

Comment: +1 Great answer. I skimmed through the article you posted and it has quite a few more...perhaps you can include? *abbo* = *basio*, *ninna* = *cuna*, *totto* = *noli facere*, *siare* = *miare*, *cacare* = ...well, we all know...

Comment: @brianpck done! also I skimmed through it too and added some words more... now it should be more or less complete

Comment: Awesome, thanks! As a quick aside, some of the words you included (like *inbulbitare*) are classified as "words used by caretakers for children"--still relevant, but slightly different