# Roman children's diminutive for parents

Tags: vocabulary

I read - I believe on here - that a Roman child's equivalent for, eg "Daddy, Pop" etc was **tata**. Was there an equivalent for "Mummy"?

Comment: My completely unsubstantiated guess would be *mama* but I have no sources on that, only a vague recollection of reading it (I think as part of a folk etymology for *mamma* "breast").

Comment: @Draconis Thanks for that, I think you're right! - http://logeion.uchicago.edu/index.html#mamma

Comment: These questions might be worth looking into: [Why did Roman children call their father 'tata' instead of 'pappa'?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1792/79) and [How did Roman babies talk?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1262/79)

Answer (score 4):

With thanks to @Draconis,found the answer, which is indeed *"mamma"*. http://logeion.uchicago.edu/index.html#mamma